# .NET 6 : context.db.Where().Orderby().ToListAsync() does not work

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, .net-6.0, ef-core-6.0

Here is my code:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Command>> GetCommandsByPlatform(Guid platformId)
{
    return await _context.Commands
                         .Where(c => c.PlatformId == platformId)
                         .ToListAsync();
}

public async Task<IEnumerable<Command>> GetCommandsByPlatform(Guid platformId)
{
    return await _context.Commands
                         .Where(c => c.PlatformId == platformId)
                         .OrderBy(c => c.Platform.Name)
                         .ToListAsync();
}
```

The only difference is that the second code has `OrderBy()` after `Where()`. The first code snippet successfully returns a list of commands, but the second one only returns an empty list.

Thank you for answering.

Comment: extract the sql generated and look at what it does

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Is this EF core 6? Please tag (and also please tag the used database system)

Comment: _"...does not work"_ is not a helpful problem description.

Comment: Is there a reason you're returning `IEnumerable<T>` instead of `List<T>`? Why _remove useful type information_?

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, you need an `Include(x => x.Platform)` in your query:

```cs
public async Task<IEnumerable<Command>> GetCommandsByPlatform(Guid platformId)
{
    return await _context.Commands
                         .Include(c => c.Platform) // this generates a join
                         .Where(c => c.PlatformId == platformId)
                         .OrderBy(c => c.Platform.Name)
                         .ToListAsync();
}
```

I'm like 75% sure that in EF Core, the `Include` is not needed, while in full EF6 it won't generate a join without it.